# Listing the information of Scanned Barcodes in ZXing

Tags: android, listview, zxing

**What I want to do:** To scan barcodes and list the information of them on the one screen.
eg. Book 1  = $30 , Book2  = $21

Something like that.

**What I am referencing:**

I found this http://as400samplecode.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-barcode-scanner-using-zxing.html and [Scanning Barcodes (ZXing) in a own Thread and displaying a ProgessDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231205/scanning-barcodes-zxing-in-a-own-thread-and-displaying-a-progessdialog)
also [Using ZXing to create an android barcode scanning app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app)

From those I  realized that I have to import IntentIntegrator, but when I import, I got several errors in that class like this :

```
The method onClick(DialogInterface, int) of type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method
The method onClick(DialogInterface, int) of type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method
```

Please kindly light me up with some examples. Because I have been reading for 5 hours and I have no idea how the thing should look like.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably compiling your project with a Java 1.5 compiler.

In Eclipse, you can change that under **Project** -> **Properties** -> **Java Compiler**. There you can try to disable **Enable Project Specific Settings**, or manually set the **Compiler compliance level** to **1.6**.